# Remove specific object from array during aggregation

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have documents with the following structure:

```
{field: ["id1", "id3"]},
{field: ["id2", "id1"]}
```

To query the documents I use

```
aggregate({$match: {'field' : { $in: ['id1'] }}})
```

I get the documents with this query but I would like only

```
{field: ["id2"]},
{field: ["id3"]}
```

I.e., I want to remove `"id1"` from the array in the aggregation step only, and not from the actual document (via an update with `$pull` or something similar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say we have following documents in a collection named `collection`:

```
db.collection.insert({field: ["id1", "id3"]})
db.collection.insert({field: ["id2", "id1"]})
```

Then below aggregation pipeline would do the trick:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {field: "id1"}
  },
  {
    $project: {
      field: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$field",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $ne: ["$$item", "id1"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The output from mongo shell is:

```
{ "field" : [ "id3" ] }
{ "field" : [ "id2" ] }
```

An alternative way is to `$unwind` the `field` and then `$group` it back:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {field: "id1"}
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$field"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      field: {
        $push: {
          $cond: {
            if: { $eq: [ "$field", "id1" ] },
            then: "$$REMOVE",
            else: "$field"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```